# 301 redirect Rule For Load Balance F5 BigIp

Tags: load-balancing, http, 301-redirect, f5-big-ip

I have a load balancer F5 Big ip for my website. Currently, I am having 302 redirect in place; however, I wanted to apply 301 but dont know how.

For example:
My website (abc.com) when typed 302 redirects to abc.com/index and when typed www.abc.com 302 redirects www.abc.com/index. I wanted to have a rule which will help me in

- abc.com - 301 redirect - www.abc.com/index
- abc.com/index - 301 redirect - www.abc.com/index
- www.abc.com - 301 redirect - www.abc.com/index

Below is the code that my tech person is trying:

Redirect to WWW

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
   if { [HTTP::host] equals "abc.com" or [HTTP::host] equals "abc.co.in" or [HTTP::host] equals "www.abc.co.in" } {
      if {!( [HTTP::path] equals "/")} {
      HTTP::respond 301 Location "http://www.abc.com[HTTP::path]"
      }
    }
}
```

Redirect POST

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
  if { [HTTP::method] equals "POST" } {
    persist source_addr
    pool shop_shop_vr4_http
  }
}
```

Redirect-VR4 HOMEPAGE

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
   if { [HTTP::path] equals "/" or [HTTP::path] starts_with "/target/" or [HTTP::path] starts_with "/logs/" or [HTTP::path] starts_with "/config/" } {
      HTTP::redirect "http://[HTTP::host]/index.jsp.vr"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at https://devcentral.f5.com/Community/GroupDetails/tabid/1082223/asg/50/aft/13481/showtab/groupforums/Default.aspx for 301 irules?

Comment: I have added some more details in the question. Please check and lemme know if you can help on this